# Who to contact for missed connection on a multi-airline flight?

Tags: air-travel, transit, airlines, missed-flights

I have flight booked through United Airlines (PRG -> FRA -> YYZ -> MCI), checked-in using the Lufthansa website (first flight PRG -> FRA is operated by Lufthansa), and the flight (FRA -> YYZ) has an Air Canada number. My flight to Toronto is delayed, and I will miss my connection flight (YYZ -> MCI) that has Air Canada number, and is operated by Air Georgian.

Who should I contact and ask to get me on the next flight? I am little bit confused by all those airlines involved.

Update: YYZ -> MCI was cancelled, and I got another flight (YYZ -> ORD -> MCI). This was promptly arranged by Air Canada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operating airline of the next segment is responsible for rerouting you if you are delayed. In this case on arrival at YYZ you will need to talk to Air Georgian. You can either go to the transfer desk to discuss it or over to their ticketing/check-in counter in departures.

If you know that FRA-YYZ is going to be delayed but you can see an alternative way of getting to MCI, then you should be proactive in talking to Air Canada (your next carrier) about rerouting options as soon as you can.

But in this circumstance I doubt there is anything faster than going to YYZ and waiting for another MCI flight.

You may find that the airline has rebooked you automatically. In many parts of the world someone would be waiting to greet you when you land in YYZ with your new boarding passes in hand and an apology. However, at YYZ I think you will need to find the airline representative yourself.

Comment: Given that Air Georgian operates under [Air Canada Express](http://www.airgeorgian.ca/) brand , do you think that Air Canada may be able to solve this?

Comment: You've got this backwards.  Officially it is the carrier that does/will deliver you late that is responsible for re-routing you.  In this case that would be Air Canada.  Air Canada in Frankfurt may be able to re-route (eg, FRA-IAD-MCI on United), or in YYZ they will be responsible for finding a new routing to MCI.

Comment: @Doc Maybe in theory, but in my experience it is best to talk to the next carrier, particularly if its their hub.

Comment: @TomasGreif Yes in that case just talk to AC

Comment: @Calchas That may be (and frequently is) the case, but it's not what your answer says.  Your answer says that the next carrier is "responsible", and they are NOT. Depending on the situations and alliances they may do it, but they are in no way responsible for doing it - the previous carrier is.

Comment: in this case Air Georgian is really not a separate entity, so either way it's Air Canada to talk to